# Genymotion not configured correctly

Tags: ubuntu, genymotion, linux-mint, nativescript

I am trying to run nativescript with genymotion but i always get the following error.

Can anybody help me please? I will appreciate any kind of help.

```
bidder-Lenovo-G500s sample-Tasks # tns emulate android --geny Mobile
Genymotion is not configured properly. Make sure you have added its installation directory to your PATH environment variable.
```

Comment: When I'm using genymotion, I just use a 'tns run android' command, and the Genymotion emulator is found like a connected device. Have you tried to just run tns run android with genymotion up?

Comment: the problem was that i was trying to run genymotion as root and i installed and i have installed the android sdk only on local user . But many thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot this [step](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/blob/master/docs/man_pages/project/testing/emulate-android.md#prerequisites) (I had the same error on MacOS and now it works)

Comment: the problem was that i was trying to run genymotion as root and i installed and i have installed the android sdk only on local user . But many thanks for trying to help!